# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view is not a child, cannot hide

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Recyclerview upgraded to v23.4.0 then find this crash：

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view is not a child, cannot hide com.xxx.ViewGroupGridView{32112cd4 V.E..... .......D 0,1443-1080,2277 #7f0b161c app:id/gv_menu_list}

    android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.unhide(ChildHelper.java:352)

    android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getScrapViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5080)
        android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4634)
        android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
        android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
        android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
        android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
        android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:584)
        android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
        android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
        android.view.View.measure(View.java:17788)
        android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:816)
        android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:561)
        android.view.View.measure(View.java:17788)
        android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5636)
        android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:459)
        android.view.View.measure(View.java:17788)
        android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:846)
        android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:512)
        android.view.View.measure(View.java:17788)
        android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5636)
        android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:459)
        android.view.View.measure(View.java:17788)
        android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5636)
        android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
        android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
        android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        android.view.View.measure(View.java:17788)
        android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5636)
        android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:459)
        com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2712)
        android.view.View.measure(View.java:17788)
        android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2482)
        android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1436)
        android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1704)
        android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1314)
        android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6715)
        android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
        android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
        android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
        android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
        android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5819)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:998)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:793)
```

[This is layout file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwzgX.png)  ViewGroupGridView is a common view which extends linearLayout,I just use this bind data in RecyclerView.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: this is layout file,the ViewGroupGridView is extends LinearLayout,it was just bind data in recyclerview

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.xxx.ViewGroupGridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gv_menu_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: @SeasonJY, did you find what the fix was?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and search on this topic shows this question and github issue for a library and one of the comments is interesting.

If you have Header or even Item with a height of `wrap_content` try changing that to fixed height and see if the crash goes away.

[Here is that comment](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/issues/78#issuecomment-230355462)

I m going to try the same, will post an update few days from now.

Comment: Nope it did not